# What does "のでは" mean at the end of a sentence?

Tags: translation, particles, manga

Below is a sentence I've come across in a manga that I'm unsure of how to translate. The context is some girls are watching a voyeur video of one of the girls undressing.

> もう早送りで / よいのでは！ (the / represents a new column of text.)

I think it has something to do with fast-forwarding the video, but I don't know. I'm especially unsure of what the "のでは" means. How does the "は" particle work at the end of a sentence? Is it supposed to be "わ" instead? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

It is 「は」, not 「わ」.  The 「は」 here is of course pronounced 「わ」 because it is a particle.

> 「もう[早送]{はやおく}りでよいのでは！」 ＝
>
> 「もう早送りでよいのでは**ないか** (ないだろうか, ないでしょうか, etc.)！」

The last part is not said but is understood between the speaker and listener.  This happens **so very** often in Japanese.

> "Maybe we should just fast-forward it from here on?"

「のでは」 is used to make a suggestion.

Comment: If this is an utterance from a girl in a casual setting, you (the OP) must expect that she's trying to make it sound overly comical. If is her inner voice, don't care about me.

Comment: can we clarify this a little bit? I think のでは at the end of the sentence itself doesn't imply the suggestion, but the contents of the sentence before it do. Isn't のでは on its own is an abbreviation of のではないか？ or んじゃなか? which people also use to confirm / say something like, "isn't it?" 

For example, in the sentence `解放しないともう空きがないのでは` のでは is attached to a state.