# What does it mean to end a question with 「だけでは？」

Tags: grammar

The context is the headline of this news article: http://www.rakumachi.jp/news/archives/148299

> これってどうなの？単に自己満足してる**だけでは**？

From the context it seems to me like perhaps an abbreviation of だけではないでしょうか。Is that close?

Comment: You're right! Here are a couple of related questions: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/22900/9831 / http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21183/9831

Answer (score 1):

> これってどうなの？単に自己満足してるだけでは？

I'd interpret it as

... 単に自己満足してるだけではない？

... 単に自己満足してるだけではないの？

The article later says: 家賃1万アップだと…180万の投資に対して回収するのに15年かかります。